# FittedBox has different behaviours when wrapping an Icon and when wrapping an IconButton

Tags: flutter

If I wrap just an Icon in a `FittedBox` with the `BoxFit.fitWidth`, the `Icon` reduces in size to the allocated amount.  If I wrap an `IconButton` in a `FittedBox` it does nothing!

How do I resize my `IconButton`?  Am I doing something wrong?  Is this a bug in Flutter or expected behaviour?

[image]

*here's my code*

```
return new Scaffold(
    body: Column(children: [
  Row(children: [
    Expanded(
        flex: 5,
        child: Container(
          child: Text('Icon button ->'),
          color: Colors.green,
        )),
    Expanded(
        flex: 1,
        child: FittedBox(
            fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
            child: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.radio,
                size: 200.0,
              ),
              onPressed: () => print('x'),
            )))
  ]),
  Row(children: [
    Expanded(
        flex: 5,
        child: Container(
          child: Text('just an Icon ->'),
          color: Colors.green,
        )),
    Expanded(
        flex: 1,
        child: FittedBox(
            fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
            child: Icon(
              Icons.radio,
              size: 200.0,
            )))
  ])
]));
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, so I needed to remove my size:200.0 from the icon, that behaviour is different between an Icon and an IconButton, if you set a size on an Icon and wrap it with a FittedBox (fitWidth) the Icon is shrunk, if you set a size on an IconButton and wrap it with a FittedBox (fitWidth) the IconButton doesn't get overridden by the FittedBox wrapper.